# Obter valor especifico em um arquivo txt

Tags: c#, regex, txt

Estou tentado obter dois valores específicos em cada linha de um arquivo txt. Conforme o exemplo:

```
15/06/2016  R$ 638,69   R$ 2.562,46
15/07/2016  R$ 672,43   R$ 2.533,51
15/08/2016  R$ 658,93   R$ 2.504,75
15/09/2016  R$ 1.362,28   R$ 2.471,80
15/10/2016  R$ 1.342,20   R$ 2.435,41
15/11/2016  R$ 1.321,80   R$ 2.398,40
```

Preciso obter de cada linha os dois valores ex: "R$ 638,69" e "R$ 2.562,46", mas como os valores podem alterar de centavos a milhões. Não tem como eu ler a string por posição! Tentei montar um `regex`mas sem sucesso. Alguém com uma ideia melhor?

```
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
                {
                    using (StreamReader texto = new StreamReader(FileUpload1.FileContent))
                    {
                        while ((mensagem = texto.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            mensagemLinha.Add(mensagem);
                        }
                    }
    for (int i = 0; i < mensagemLinha.Count; i++)
                    {
                        string re1 = "()";  
                        string re2 = ".*?"; 
                        string re3 = "(\\$)";  
                        string re4 = "( )"; 
                        string re5 = ".*?"; 
                        string re6 = "(,)"; 
                        string re7 = ".*?"; 
                        string re8 = "(R)"; 
                        string re9 = "(\\$)";  
                        string re10 = "( )";    
                        string re11 = ".*?";    
                        string re12 = "(\\.)"; 
                        string re13 = ".*?";   
                        string re14 = "(,)";

                        Regex rex = new Regex(re1 + re2 + re3 + re4 + re5 + 
                        re6 + re7 + re8 + re9 + re10 + re11 + re12 + 
                        re13 + re14, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);

                        Match valores = rex.Match((mensagemLinha[i].ToString()));

                        lblArq.Text += valores ;
    }
```

Comment: Se a informação é esta pegue o dado pela posição que ele está.

Comment: @Maniero as posições não são fixas, dependendo das casas decimais a posição da blocagem é alterada. Veja que a posição dos valores das linhas 4,5,6 foram deslocadas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como disse o Maniero: "Se a informação é esta pegue o dado pela posição que ele está".

Ou seja, pelo exemplo que você publicou, não é necessário usar uma regex.

```cs
using System;
using static System.Console;

class MainClass 
{
    public static void Main (string[] args) 
    {
        var linhasArquivo = new [] 
        { 
            "15/06/2016  R$ 638,69   R$ 2.562,46",
            "15/07/2016  R$ 672,43   R$ 2.533,51",
            "15/08/2016  R$ 658,93   R$ 2.504,75",
            "15/09/2016  R$ 1.362,28   R$ 2.471,80",
            "15/10/2016  R$ 1.342,20   R$ 2.435,41",
            "15/11/2016  R$ 1.321,80   R$ 2.398,40",
            "15/11/2016  R$ 789.785.987.498,40   R$ 287.654.987.498,40",
        };

        foreach(var linha in linhasArquivo)
        {
            var firstIndex = linha.IndexOf("R$") + 3; // +3 para contar o símbolo + espaço
            var lastIndex = linha.LastIndexOf("R$") + 3;

            var valor2 = linha.Substring(lastIndex);
            // Qualquer coisa a partir do último 'R$ '
            var valor1 = linha.Substring(firstIndex, linha.Length - firstIndex - valor2.Length - 3 - 3) ;
            // Qualquer coisa a partir do primeiro 'R$ ', até o próximo espaço

            WriteLine($"{valor1} - {valor2} ");
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no Repl.it**](https://repl.it/@jfbueno/ptso421131)</sup>

Comment: Se não se importar, usei mesmos dados que mockou pra fazer um outro exemplo mas com regex. :)

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann Na boa, fica a vontade.

Answer (score 2):

Com `regex` poderia fazer assim:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;
using static System.Console;

class MainClass 
{
    public static void Main (string[] args) 
    {
        var linhasArquivo = new [] 
        { 
            "15/06/2016  R$ 638,69   R$ 2.562,46",
            "15/07/2016  R$ 672,43   R$ 2.533,51",
            "15/08/2016  R$ 658,93   R$ 2.504,75",
            "15/09/2016  R$ 1.362,28   R$ 2.471,80",
            "15/10/2016  R$ 1.342,20   R$ 2.435,41",
            "15/11/2016  R$ 1.321,80   R$ 2.398,40",
            "15/11/2016  R$ 789.785.987.498,40   R$ 287.654.987.498,40",
        };

        foreach(var linha in linhasArquivo)
        {
            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(linha, @"(?:R\$\s?)(\d*\.*)*\d*,\d+");
            Console.WriteLine($"Achou {matches.Count} ocorrências...");

            var arrValues = matches.Cast<Match>()
                            .Select(m => m.Value)
                            .ToArray();
            //faça um foreach aqui se for necessário
            Console.WriteLine($"valor 1 = {arrValues[0]}");
            Console.WriteLine($"valor 2 = {arrValues[1]}");
        }
    }
}
```

Também [coloquei no repl.it](https://repl.it/@GeorgeWurthmann/SOpt421131) pra ver funcionando.